# Datetime from attributetable to layername in QGIS with Python

Tags: pyqgis, loop, datetime, layer-name

I have several (point) layers and I want for all of them this >
Take the first value of the "datetime" column and append it on the layername.

These point layers come from gpx track records and I now want to have this layer name format:

YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm_*

Until now it is in this format : YYYY-MM-DD_*

CODE (not working):

```
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer
for layer in iface.mapCanvas().layers():
    datetime_value =  layer.fields['datetime']
    formatted_datetime = datetime_value.toString('yyyyMMdd_HHmmss')
    new_layer_name = f"{layer.name()}_{formatted_datetime}"
    layer.setName(new_layer_name)
    print(f"Layernames for '{layer.name()}' updated successfully.")
```

Error: `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the feature's attribute for the "datetime" field, not the layer's fields directly. You need to make sure that the "datetime" field is available in the layer.

```
for layer in iface.mapCanvas().layers():
    
    # Check if the layer has a "datetime" field
    if 'datetime' in [field.name() for field in layer.fields()]:
        # Get the first feature in the layer
        first_feature = next(layer.getFeatures())
        print(first_feature)

        # Get the value of the "datetime" attribute from the first feature
        datetime_value = first_feature['datetime']

        # Format the datetime
        formatted_datetime = datetime_value.toString('yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss')

        # Create a new layer name
        new_layer_name = f"{layer.name()}_{formatted_datetime}"

        # Set the new layer name
        layer.setName(new_layer_name)

        print(f"Layernames for '{layer.name()}' updated successfully.")
    else:
        print(f"Layer '{layer.name()}' does not have a 'datetime' field.")
```

Comment: great, thx... that works for me !

Comment: Happy to hear. Please accept my answer if it is working. Thx